# How to get existing pandas dataframe from a string variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of dataframes which are sequentially named in the format "set1", "set2", "set3" ....

I need to run a for loop across all the dataframes to carry out various operations in this dataframes.

How will I convert the string "set1" to the dataframe set1 so that I can carry out operations like set1.index,  set1.columns e.t.c

Comment: please share  certain codes which you have tried till now , and what are the errors you facing?Share any example set.

Comment: I have not received any approapriate information regarding the issue even after a lot of research, hence I have not executed any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether the variables are located in the global environment or are local to the scope you are working in, you can use

```py
## access global variable by string name
globals()['set1']

## access local variable by string name
locals()['set1']
```